# Scala test java REST API framework

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

We have REST API written in Java . 
I want to write some unit tests in Scala to the REST API.
I am looking for a lean, easy to use framework to use (an example or link to example can be helpful) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Play! framework WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS) works really well in my opinion. You can use it as a standalone module [as described here](http://carminedimascio.com/2015/02/how-to-use-the-play-ws-library-in-a-standalone-scala-app/).

Some examples from the linked page:

**GET request with authentication:**

```
WS.url(url).withAuth(user, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).get()
```

**GET request with query parameters:**

```
WS.url(url).withQueryString("paramKey" -> "paramValue").get()
```

**POST request with JSON body:**

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val data = Json.obj(
  "key1" -> "value1",
  "key2" -> "value2"
)
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = WS.url(url).post(data)
```

That last one also requires you to import the Play! JSON library. If you don't need to manipulate them, you can always just pass your JSON payload serialised as a string - without having to use the JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

You should try SPECS 2: [Link to SPECS2 Web](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/)

I recommend you to use it with [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) to have the best tools to test your API.